# How to extract multiple columns into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying very hard to implement the below requirements, but I am not understanding is it possible to do using sql server. Kindly suggest me.

In the below table for every ID there may be 1 X mark or 2 X marks or 3 X marks in other columns as shown in below table. So I need to write a query to get a new column name with all the X marked columns. Kindly refer the output table sample.

**Table1**

| Id | CurrentAmount | RiskRating | ShortName | NoExceptions | ABCD | EFGH | IJKL | MNOP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1010 | 100 | 2 | John Krsp | *null* | X | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 1011 | 200 | 5 | David sku | *null* | X | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 1022 | 300 | 1 | Patrik | *null* | X | X | X | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=387d8ab4d6d42197e72fb111131fc4b1)*

**Desired Output:**

| Id | CurrentAmount | RiskRating | ShortName | ExceptionCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1010 | 100 | 2 | John Krsp | ABCD |
| 1011 | 200 | 5 | David sku | ABCD |
| 1022 | 300 | 1 | Patrik | ABCD |
| 1022 | 300 | 1 | Patrik | EFGH |
| 1022 | 300 | 1 | Patrik | IJKL |

Comment: Please post all queries, data samples and expected results as text NOT as images. We can't copy text from screen shots...

Comment: I am unable to add the sample data, its always taking wrong format

Comment: Anyone here can help by editing the question later if the formatting is off. You can also create a fiddle and post the SQL, using http://sqlfiddle.com/   Try the "Text to DDL" option which let's you paste delimited data and create the DDL from it automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have added the sample data, Kindly help me, Thank you in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUE`

```
select t1.id,
       t1.CurrentAmount,
       t1.RiskRating,
       t1.ShortName,
       v.Expectioncode
from table1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
   VALUES (ABCD,'ABCD'),
   (EFGH,'EFGH'),
   (IJKL,'IJKL'),
   (MNOP,'MNOP')
) v (val,Expectioncode)
WHERE v.val IS NOT NULL
```

**Edit**

From your comment, If some of the data types are not `varchar` you can try to use `CAST` as the same type (from your sample code you might cast as `VARCHAR(10)` which might as same as other columns.) otherwise you might get a converting error.

```
select t1.id,
       t1.CurrentAmount,
       t1.RiskRating,
       t1.ShortName,
       v.Expectioncode
from table1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
   VALUES (ABCD,'ABCD'),
   (EFGH,'EFGH'),
   (IJKL,'IJKL'),
   (CAST(MNOP AS VARCHAR(10)),'MNOP')
) v (val,Expectioncode)
WHERE v.val IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4d977690fa2828e1ff9c1c27435aa912)

Comment: Thank you D-Shih, there is one column 'MNOP' which is in float data type, so I am getting an error, can you please suggest me. "Error converting data type varchar to float."

Comment: @user17824023 I edit my answer hope that help

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the UNPIVOT function. One advantage is that the column names do not have to be defined again.

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[CurrentAmount]
      ,[RiskRating]
      ,[ShortName]
      ,ExceptionCode
  FROM (Select [Id]
      ,[CurrentAmount]
      ,[RiskRating]
      ,[ShortName]
      , ABCD, EFGH, IJKL, CAST(MNOP AS VARCHAR(10)) MNOP
      FROM [Table1]) p
  UNPIVOT 
    (ExceptionCode_Value FOR ExceptionCode IN
        (ABCD, EFGH, IJKL, MNOP)) AS unpvt;
```